Quasar dev PSSecurityException
I'm using quasar to run my app using the "quasar dev" command, it always worked fined. Today it stopped working suddently and I get this error:
quasar : Impossible de charger le fichier C:\Users\GLEU\AppData\Roaming\npm\quasar.ps1. Le fichier [...] n’est pas signé 
numériquement. Vous ne pouvez pas exécuter ce script sur le système actuel. Pour plus d’informations sur l’exécution de scripts et la définition de stratégies 
d’exécution, voir la rubrique about_Execution_Policies à l’adresse https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ quasar dev
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : Erreur de sécurité : (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

I looked around and try to edit the ExecutionPolicy, but even whith this ExecutionPolicy:
        Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy       AllSigned
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process    Unrestricted or Bypass
  CurrentUser    Unrestricted or Bypass
 LocalMachine    RemoteSigned

I still get the error and I don't know what to do to unlock the situation, and I don't understand why it changed in the first place?

I encountered that issue aswell.
The Problem is, that the MachinePolicy is 'AllSigned'. Since it is the highest Level Policy, the lower ones will be ignored (see Microsoft about_Execution_Policies) and your script cant be executed.
To solve this Issue you need your Network Admin to change the MachinePolicy by changing the Group Policies (see docs).
The reason for the change is probably a Settings change from your Network Admin.
